Complex bilinear form has no signature.
Let $\mathbb C^4$ be the complex vector space equipped with the symmetric bilinear form  $$b(z,w) =  z_1w_1 + z_2 w_2- z_3 w_3- z_4 w_4$$ where the natrix of the bilinear form is given by $$ A= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0&0& 0\\ 0 &1&0&0 \\ 0&0&-1&0\\0&0&0&-1 \end{pmatrix}$$
I want to prove that any nondegenerate symmetric bilinear form on $\mathbb C^4$
is equivalent to the standard one $b(z,w) = \sum_{i=1}^4 z_iw_i$up to change of basis.
My attempt: Consider the new basis $\{(1,0,0,0), (0,1,0,0), (0,0,i,0), (0,0,0,i)\}$. Let $P$ be the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0&0& 0\\ 0 &1&0&0 \\ 0&0&i&0\\0&0&0&i \end{pmatrix}$$ Therefore, $$B = P^t A P = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0&0& 0\\ 0 &1&0&0 \\ 0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1 \end{pmatrix}$$ Therefore the bilinear form wrt $B$ is $$b(z,w) = z_1w_1 + z_2 w_2+ z_3 w_3+ z_4 w_4.$$
Is my solution correct?

Looks good to me.

Doubly unclear: 1) your $b$ denotes two distinct forms ($z_1w_1 + z_2 w_2- z_3 w_3- z_4 w_4$ and $z_1w_1 + z_2 w_2+ z_3 w_3+ z_4 w_4$). 2) If you "want to prove that any nondegenerate symmetric bilinear form on $\mathbb C^4$
is equivalent to the standard one", doing it for a particular one does not suffice.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification: For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.
